# Use cleanthesis theme: french accent problem on MacOS X

Tags: packages, accents, french, cleanthesis

I use the "cleanthesis" (http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) theme to write a French traineeship report but I have a problem with the accents. My é are convert to Ó (with double quote)

I use these packages because I am on MacOS X:

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Please can you give me few leads?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Probably your editor is not set for the `applemac` encoding; try `latin1`

Comment: I tried but its not working !

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: What about `utf8` input encoding? With Unicode all accents should work fine.

Comment: I second @ralfix's suggestion. French and `utf8` go well together (though your document and bibliography files must also be `utf-8` encoded). If it does not work, could you try without the `cleanthesis` package and see if it changes anything? Try using just the `book`, `article`, `report` or `memoir` class, and tell us if it changes anything (so we can know if it is an editor/encoding or a `cleanthesis` problem).

Comment: i haven't problems when i use book, article, report...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally write Latex in french in OSX and use `utf-8`encoding like so

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Everything the works well. To make sure you set your editor to encode using `utf-8`. This is how i do using vim.

```
set fileencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```